# Matrix logarithms for various algebraic groups

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups

For any field $k$ of characteristic $p$ the sets
$$\left\{g \in GL_n(k) \ \middle| \ g^p = 1\right\} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \left\{x \in \mathbb M_n(k) \ \middle| \ x^p = 0\right\}$$
are in bijection.  The maps either way are given by the matrix exponential and matrix logarithm.  I'd like to know if this bijection between $p$-unipotent elements of the group and $p$-nilpotent elements of the Lie algebra restricts to a similar bijection for certain closed subgroups of $GL_n(k)$.

It's not true in general, but it's not hard to show that for $SL$, $SO$, and $Sp$ the matrix exponential restricts appropriately.  Also if $A$ is an algebra and we look at algebra automorphisms $Aut(A) \subseteq GL(A)$ then the exponential map takes derivations $Der(A) \subseteq End(A)$ to automorphisms.

Where I'm stuck is I can't figure out if the logarithm restricts as well, or equivalently if the restriction of the exponential is still surjective.  I can show this works for $SL_n$ but I'm stuck on the others.  This has to be written down somewhere, but I can't find any good references either.

Comment: Just before Lemma 1.7 in [this paper](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0157/inf1par.pdf) the authors introduce the notion of an embedding/subgroup of exponential type.  They then state (w/o proof) in Lemma 1.8 that the classical groups are subgroups of exponential type.  I'm not sure if this answers your question, but it may be relevant.

Comment: Jared as in Friedlanders student?  We talked at the conference last week.  Basically I'm trying to show that these groups are "logarithmic type".  I just figured out $SO$ using a nasty combinatorial argument.  I was really hoping that this was known and there'd be a slick way to do it.

Comment: Hey Jim!  Good to hear from you.  Sorry for the unhelpful comment.  I'll try to give this some thought tomorrow.  Hope you are doing well.